# Error while creating folder using Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I am using the following code to create one folder in Eclipse Luna.

```
public static IFolder createFolder(final IPath path) throws CoreException {
    final IFolder folder = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFolder(path);

    final IContainer parent = folder.getParent();
    if (parent instanceof IFolder && !parent.exists()) {
        createFolder(parent.getFullPath());
    }
    folder.create(true, true, null);
    return folder;    
}
```

Here path value is like `/MyProject/resources/myFolder` and **resources** folder already exists.
It is throwing an exception and not creating the folder. But the same code works with Eclipse Juno.

Exception:

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: The resource tree is locked for modifications.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkManager.checkIn(WorkManager.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.prepareOperation(Workspace.java:2251)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Folder.create(Folder.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Folder.create(Folder.java:125)
.
.
.
    org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:283)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:274)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:159)
```

**How can I solve the above  issues I am encountering in Eclipse Luna ?**

Comment: Throwing what exception? There has not been any change to these APIs between Juno and Luna.

Comment: which release version ?

Comment: I am using Luna r version @SkorpEN

Comment: Write exact version. Did U use same workspace for both eclipse???

Comment: I am using Luna release(4.4.0) and build id :20140612-0600.I am not using same workspace but both have same classes and files.